# DialogFragment with custom shape

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, android-dialogfragment, android-viewgroup

how to create a dialog fragment with the custom shape?

I have an icon that needs to be placed on top of the dialog window (with transparency).

[image]

The dialog itself should be:

[image: Dialog screen]

The dialog layout:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/server_error_title"
                android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:text="@string/server_error_title"
                android:textColor="@color/soft_blue"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"/>
            <View
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:id="@+id/server_error_divider"
                android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/server_error_title"
                android:background="@color/soft_blue" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/server_error_message"
                android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/server_error_divider"
                style="@style/TextDialog"
                android:text="@string/server_error_message"/>
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:id="@+id/server_error_large_divider"
                android:layout_marginTop="51dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/server_error_message"
                android:background="@color/greyish"/>
           <LinearLayout
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:gravity="center_horizontal"
               android:background="@color/white_grey"
               android:layout_below="@id/server_error_large_divider">
               <Button
                   android:layout_width="320dp"
                   android:layout_height="46dp"
                   android:id="@+id/server_error_close_btn"
                   android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                   android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                   style="@style/TextButton2"
                   android:text="@string/server_error_close_btn"
                   android:background="@drawable/big_button_shape" />
           </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/error_dialog_icon"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_error_circle"
            android:layout_gravity="center|top"/>
    </FrameLayout>
```

But what I'm getting is this:

[image]

Do I need a custom ViewGroup or it could be done in an easier way?

Comment: use minus margin on ImageView

Comment: @vrundpurohit didn't work :( http://i.imgur.com/5o22GDL.png

Comment: ofc give some padding top to your FrameLayout.

Comment: Modify  the cross icon with rounded white padding background and try to use the answer provided by @W4R10CK

Comment: @W4R10CK sorry, I've tried your solution, but it didn't work for me, so I've only added +1 to your answer.

Comment: Didn't you use term **setContentView(R.layout.test); worked like a charm**, The layout is still mine :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use following sample code for your xml:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/server_error_title"
                android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:text="@string/server_error_title"
                android:textColor="@color/soft_blue"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"/>
            <View
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:id="@+id/server_error_divider"
                android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/server_error_title"
                android:background="@color/soft_blue" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/server_error_message"
                android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/server_error_divider"
                style="@style/TextDialog"
                android:text="@string/server_error_message"/>
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:id="@+id/server_error_large_divider"
                android:layout_marginTop="51dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/server_error_message"
                android:background="@color/greyish"/>
           <LinearLayout
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:gravity="center_horizontal"
               android:background="@color/white_grey"
               android:layout_below="@id/server_error_large_divider">
               <Button
                   android:layout_width="320dp"
                   android:layout_height="46dp"
                   android:id="@+id/server_error_close_btn"
                   android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                   android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                   style="@style/TextButton2"
                   android:text="@string/server_error_close_btn"
                   android:background="@drawable/big_button_shape" />
           </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/error_circle">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/error_dialog_icon"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_error_circle"
            android:layout_gravity="center|top"/>

        </FrameLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
```

and error_circle:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:innerRadius="0dp"
    android:shape="oval"
    android:useLevel="false" >
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

    <stroke
        android:width="45dp"
        android:color="@android:color/white" />
</shape>
```

**Edit:**

And in the onCreateView() of the DialogFragment:

```
getDialog().requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Comment: With requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); and setContentView(R.layout.test); worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

You can put your `Views(custom button, layout)`, inside `LinearLayout` as per your idea.

Dialog method, Make `Window` transparent:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.test);
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
dialog.show();
```

test.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
    android:background="#f00"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Result(avoid BG)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

try like this, it will show you transparent dialog

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext, android.R.style.Theme_Panel);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);
            dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
            TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.----);
            dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create style and set your shape as background for example:

```
<style name="MyDialogFragmentStyl" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/my_dialog_background</item>
</style>
```